# Cookie not showing up on response from cross origin api get request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, axios

Update: When I go to the api route in the url the cookie is set but is not set when made with a javascript request.
I am trying to set the cookie on a cross origin request. According to the Node.js docs I can do:

```
router.route("/:id").get(
    function(req,res){
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'beer=sour');
        console.log('response: ', res);
        res.sendStatus(200)
    })
```

Or with express, the function:

```
function(req,res){
    res.cookie('name', 'tobi', {});
     res.sendStatus(200)
}
```

Which appears to set it when I console log the response to the server before I send.

```
{ 'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
 'set-cookie':
  [ 'Set-Cookie',
    'name=tobi; Domain=.example.com; Path=/admin; Secure' ] } }
```

On the client's response I am unable to find the cookie!

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/authentication/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
    .then(function(data){
      console.log('data: ', data)
    })
  }
```

logs:

```
 headers:
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        __proto__: Object
```

Perhaps I'm assuming it would be under 'headers' as the logically makes sense. But no where else in the response object can I find the cookie.

I have looked under document.cookie in the console too.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Presumably the server setting this isn't `example.com`?

Comment: Ooops yes. I just removed the options object but still see nothing.